# Deleting attached files when its post deleted

Tags: php, jquery, node.js

Imagine there is writing article application, The article would have some pictures, files, etc. Of course, when the article removed, attached files should be removed too. But How can I do that?

There is write form, in 
`/news/write`. When I uploads some picture, the picture will send to the server in background, (by ajax post). and this picture will have some name, like `a0bb880c5a06b5b9dc238f84cfda6861`, it will be appended in the editor `<img src="/uploads/a0bb880c5a06b5b9dc238f84cfda6861">`.

I don't finish the article, but the picture in the server. Finally I submit the post, and there is picture with in it, And later few hours, I want to delete it. No problem with delete article itselt, but the picutre remains in the server. I want to delete it too.

I think some ways, The conclusion is, I should bind article and its picture.

1. Mapping files and article - But how can I do that? the article not exist, so I don't know article's id.
2. When article saved, parsing content and pick up `<img>` tag's src attribute, and connect it. Should I do like this? Is there any easier way?
3. Or delete files periodly ...?

Comment: What database are you using? Are you adding image tag directly to article body as image tag?

Comment: @Yalamber Yes, I'm using mongodb, Yes when image uploaded finish the img tag will append in editor content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a relation with your article and image files to be able to delete the image file when article is deleted.

You can also parse through the content of the articles and find images and delete them but I think that will be bad way to do it.

Instead try this.
When you save articles you can save images files in a field of the articles document.

```
db.articles.insert( { title: "article title", body: 'article body', images: [{imageFileName: 'xyz.jpg'}, {imageFileName: 'xyz.png'}...] } );
```

Now when you delete article you will have images field that you can iterate through and delete the image files as well.

Comment: But how? how can I know image file name without parsing img tag?

Comment: When you upload an image and append it to the editor you can also append that image file name in the hidden input field. That way when you submit form you will get the image file name as well.

Comment: It would be a solution, I will try that tonight!